# Analytic, continuity and existence of the antiderivative in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let me allow to introduce the 2 statements.

First question) For any region $\in D(\subset \mathbb{C})$

"$\exists F s.t. F'(z) = f(z)$ on $D$ $\Rightarrow$ $f \in H(D)$ "

(The notation $f \in H(D)$ means $f$ is analytic on $D$)

I tried proving the above statement because it is clear for me. But Nothing come to mind for prove that. If my guess is right, Does anyone give me some hint to prove that? (If the statement is not true, What the condition we need not only for the existence of the antiderivatve?)

Second question)

$\exists F s.t. F'(z) = f(z)$ on $D$ $\Rightarrow$ $f \in C(D)$

(Here the $C(D)$ is a set of all functions whose element $f$ is continuous on 
$D$.)

This is not true at least I thought. Because Considering in real case, though $f$ is discontinuous on countable points $p$, $f$ is Riemann-integrable(I.e. $\exists F(z)$  ) So We can take some counterexample like real case. Is my guess right? If the second statement is true, Would you say why it is true?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any constraints on $f$ and $D$ other than what is written here?  For instance could we have $f(z) = 1/z$ and $D = \{z \in \Bbb{C} : 1 \leq |z| \leq 2\}$, the annulus centered at $0$ with radii $1$ and $2$?

Comment: That is not a counter example Eric. The statement is IF you have a antiderivative then you are analytic. It says nothing about functions without antiderivatives on a given region.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh : If I thought it was a counterexample, I would have written an Answer.  Students routinely forget to mention closedness, openness, connectedness or path connectedness, for example.

Comment: Region means an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ in complex analysis texts. I feel you are confusing yourself with the converse which needs a simply connected assumption.

Comment: Is $D$ still a region in your second question @se-hyuck yang?

Comment: @Ciaran  Yes. All the D is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions who are differentiable in the complex sense are locally expressible as power series and so analytic. The derivative of an analytic function is analytic and hence continuous too.

Also be careful not to mix up being Riemann-integrable with having an antiderivative. The function which is 1 at zero and 0 elsewhere is Riemann integrable but does not have an antiderivative. It has an antiderivative almost everywhere, but not everywhere.